# The format specified for uint64_t is giving an error

Tags: c

When I try to compile this code I get the errors saying `error: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t **’ {aka ‘long unsigned int **’}` and `error: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t *’ {aka ‘long unsigned int *’}`

So how am I supposed to format testInteger to take uint64?

```
  #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
    int main(void) {
    
        uint64_t* testInteger = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    
        scanf("%lu", &testInteger);  
        printf("%lu", testInteger);
        free(testInteger);
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%lu", testInteger); printf("%lu", *testInteger);`

Comment: Appley, Good to have compiled with many warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `testInteger` is a pointer.  In the first, instance `&testInteger` is realized as a pointer to a pointer since the pointer address is being referenced by `&`.  In the second case, a pointer is being used directly.  Function `printf` expects an integer value and function `scanf` expects a pointer where `%lu` is used.  For `scanf` just use `testInteger` directly and for `printf` use `*testInteger` which will use the value stored rather than the pointer itself.

Answer (score 3):

With `uint64_t* testInteger = ... scanf("%lu", &testInteger);`, `"%lu"` does not match a `uint64_t**`, but a `unsigned long *`.

> how am I supposed to format testInteger to take uint64?

To read a `uint64_t` (not uint64), use `"%" SCNu64` from `<inttypes.h>` and `uint64_t *`.
To write a `uint64_t` (not uint64), use `"%" PRIu64` from `<inttypes.h>` and `uint64_t`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...

uint64_t* testInteger = malloc(sizeof *testInteger);
if (testInteger != NULL) {
  if (scanf("%" SCNu64, testInteger) == 1) {//No & here,testInteger is a pointer 
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", *testInteger);  // Use a * here
  }
}
```

It is a good idea to test for the success of `malloc()` and `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

scanf as argument receive pointer, since testInteger is already pointer your &testInteger will pass pointer on pointer and that is invalid. You should only pass testInteger to scanf, not &testInteger. And in the print testInteger should be dereferenced. Your code should be:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  uint64_t* testInteger = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));

  scanf("%lu", testInteger);
  printf("%lu", *testInteger);
  free(testInteger);
}
```